# Extracting table from html using python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the table "Pharmacology-and-Biochemistry"from the url https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/23677941#section=Pharmacology-and-Biochemistry i have written this code

```
from lxml import etree
import urllib.request as ur
url = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound  /23677941#section=Chemical-and-Physical-Properties"
web = ur.urlopen(url)
s = web.read()

html = etree.HTML(s)
print (html)

nodes = html.xpath('//li[@id="Pharmacology-and-Biochemistry"/descendant::*]')
print (tr_nodes)
```

but the script is not getting the node specified in xpath and output is empty list 
[]
 I tried several other xpaths but nothing worked!
please help me !!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that in this url doesn't exists the table that you are searching.

Try to run this:

```
from urllib import urlopen
text = urlopen('https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/23677941#section=Pharmacology-and-Biochemistry').read()
print 'Pharmacology-and-Biochemistry' in text
```

The result is:

```
False
```